# Is this a correct usage of a gerund?

Tags: gerunds

I have already used structures such as "I don't like him singing the song" or "I don't like his singing the song". It dates back to years age when I learned it. So I wonder if I can use the following structure:

> In these stories, the reader still expects the story to continue and receives no sign of the story ending.

where, I refer to *ending* as a gerund.
I am quite tempted to use this sentence and it sounds right. However, I don't know if It is correct grammatically and why if so?

Comment: Ending is a noun, why should it be a gerund in your sentence?  or ..receives no singn that the story is ending!

Comment: It's perfectly grammatical and idiomatic, though the triple use of the word "story" might draw too much attention to the text rather than the message; a native speaker might use pronouns in place of one or more of the "*stories*" (e.g. "... *its ending*").

Comment: It's fine. "ending" = "coming to an end" here. Why the doubt?

Comment: @josh there's more than one error in your reasoning.

Comment: A gerund is a verb used as a noun, e.g. *At the ending of an era, a new one starts*. But I am not clear that 'I see no sign of the story ending' is a gerund. How can *ending* be a noun in that phrase?

Comment: @Kris I was doubtful whether it was OK to use a gerund after a noun. I had in mind only its practice after pronouns like his/him/etc.

Comment: They are not the same grammatically. Both are correct.

Comment: I am with @WS2. Clearly the *ending* here is just a present participle. There is no sign of the story *doing something*.

Comment: @WS2 How should be a sign like, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful way to tell whether an -ing form is a noun or a verb is to see whether it would need an adjective or an adverb to modify it. Sometimes it's ambiguous, but not here. "...receives no sign of the story sudden ending"* plainly sounds wrong, whereas "...receives no sign of the story suddenly ending" is fine. "Ending" in that sentence needs an adverb, not an adjective, so it's unambiguously a verb, not a noun. It's not a gerund.